# datetime format

Tags: c#

Below command returns with time stamp, how do I get rid of the time:

```
String.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date))
```

Comment: erm, DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()   ?

Comment: You know that DateTime.Today returns the same thing as DateTime.Now.Date right?

Comment: I don't see a time, just the date.  but this simplified syntax works too:  String.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}",DateTime.Today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

**OR**

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
```

src: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()`...this has the bonus of obeying culture rules.