# Datetime Format Convert C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Here is my date time format displayed

Dr["DATE"]       =========>     Jun 27 2014 9:06PM

I want it to display like this one =========> 27.06.2014

Here is my code:

```
ltrlNotlar.Text = Dr["DATE"].ToString()
```

How to change first format to the second one?

Thankss

Comment: What is `Dr`? A DataRow? A DataReader?

Comment: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) will undoubtedly be useful to you.

Comment: This has been asked [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162243/datetime-format) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900208/format-datetime-in-c-sharp) before in other ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use DateTime to do the conversion for you

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(Dr["DATE"].ToString());

ltrlNotlar.Text = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: There's no need to instantiate a new variable to do this. You can do it in a more readable single liner and with less overhead.

Comment: For the sake of explanation, it seemed splitting the logic into two parts would convey the solution better

Comment: There - fixed that for you.

Comment: Sorry t this Dr not DataRow. Dr is DataReader.

Answer (score 2):

If `Dr` is a `DataRow`, you can this

```
ltrlNotlar.Text = dr.Field<DateTime>("DATE").ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

I like using `.Field` because it does the casting for you. However this only works if the sql column is a `Date` or `DateTime` (or possibly `DateTimeOffset`). If you are storing your date as a string in the database, this won't work.

If the sql column `DATE` is nullable, make sure to change the generic argument to `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use something like this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(SomeDateTime).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```